# Issue with uploading file to BIM 360 using forge API

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

I am using two-legged authentication for uploading files to BIM, the bucket API response says success but I cannot see files in the respective folder.

The response  from Bucket api is like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BePMC.png

Any suggestions on the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look you haven't created the first version tip. Here is the tutorial page:

https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/tutorials/document-management/upload-document/#step-7-create-the-first-version-of-the-file

Comment: Yes i tried creating version please find the below response i received                        
 AsyncState =null,                                                                               
 cancellationPending=false,                                                                  CreationOptions=None,                                                                                     
  Exception=null,                                                                                                               
  id=11,     Result=null,      status=WatingForActivation

Comment: Sorry, the error message you posted looks not from Forge. Please try to use other tools like Postman to help narrow down the issue. Here is my postman script and check the `Data Management API for BIM360` part. https://github.com/yiskang/forge.api.postman